# How to detect control character (ex. 0x0A (line feed)) with java?

Tags: java, detection, control-characters

I need to count the number of control characters from a text document.

Comment: Looks like homework. What you did so far ?

Comment: Read the document char by char and count...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because zero effort went into   asking it.

Comment: So far I can only count the number of "normal" characters. (such as a, b, c...)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your input char by char and compare the character's ordinal number with the [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) defined in ASCII standard. If you have a match, increase your counter.

---

**Edit:**

```
  String input = "325\nfefe\rw2";

  int normalCount = 0;
  int controlCount = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {

     int characterCode = (int)input.charAt(i);

     if (characterCode == 10 || characterCode == 13) { // Match \n and \r
        ++controlCount;
     }
     else {
        ++normalCount;
     }
  }

  System.out.println("The input contains:");
  System.out.println("\t" + normalCount + " printable characters");
  System.out.println("\t" + controlCount + " control characters");
```

Will give you this output:

```
The input contains:
    9 printable characters
    2 control characters
```

Comment: It seems that the major problem is that when I use s.length() (s is a String), it will only give me the number of normal characters (a,b,c...) in the String.

Comment: That is not true. ``length()`` will also count control characters. The documentation states "*Returns the length of this string. The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string.*" I edited my answer above, where I'm matching line feeds and carriage returns only, but you can process other control characters alike.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find [the isISOControl method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl(char)) from the Character class useful. It returns true is the character is a control character.

Supposing temp is a String and counter is an int where you want to have the total of control characters in the string, someting like this might do the trick:

```
   for (int i=0,counter=0;i<temp.length();i++) {
        if (!Character.isISOControl(temp.charAt(i))) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33706971)